# Run VNC only for a region of the screen

Tags: vnc, remote-control

Is there a VNC server that lets me define only a region of the screen for remote control?

Comment: like CITRIX for application sharing? Or you mean on the client side that manages the VNC instance, you only want to resize the client view?

Comment: @Jakub no not on the client side. I want the server to serve only a small portion of the screen (because all the action happens in that part and its a waste to send the entire screen)

Comment: Is stuff actually changing on the rest of the screen? VNC usually only transmits portions of the screen that change, so unless you have other applications on outside this region that are constantly changing, VNC is already only sending the changing regions.

Comment: @DarthAndroid this is extremely interesting, do you know any source that says this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's meaningful to have remote control only on a region of your screen. Once you gave remote user control of your keyboard and mouse, they can easily pull in the rest of windows outside of the display region... If you're giving a read only permission, it might make more sense.

Comment: It could make sanse to control only a region of the screen, in those cases where the internet connection speed is very low and you want to minimize the exchanged data with the VNC server...

Answer (score 0):

If the reason why you need this is because of **bandwith limitations** (e.g. low connection speed), then, as Darth Android said in a comment, VNC already transmits only *portions* of the screen that change.

In particular, VNC uses the [RFB protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6143) (Remote FrameBuffer) (see [this](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002320638-How-does-VNC-technology-work-)), which is based on *incremental* updates of pixels, and the official RFC for the protocol says:

> If the client has not lost any contents of the area in which it is
> interested, then it sends a FramebufferUpdateRequest with incremental
> set to non-zero (true).  If and when there are changes to the
> specified area of the framebuffer, the server will send a
> FramebufferUpdate.

If you read the terminology at the beginning of the RFC, it is clear that by ***area*** they mean a ***portion*** of the screen (its corresponding pixels), and since only the changing pixels are transmitted, if the rest of the screen is not touched then only the portion on which you are interested will be transmitted to the client.